# Perfect amount of HCl to precipitate 1.000g of silver alloy

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

I am trying to figure out the perfect amount of HCl to drop silver out of a solution for a specific alloy.
This alloy is 79.5% - 80.25 % Ag.
We digest this (size of the sample is usually 1.000g or 0.999g) alloy in 10 mL of a 30% HNO3, once fully dissolved 60 mL's of DIH2O is added then 2.5 mL of HCl is added to precipitate AgCl. (Side note: the amount of AgCl that is ideal for this procedure is around 1.06 g.)
We have been noticing that we have to refilter the sample because AgCl precipitates out of filtrate the next day.
Any suggestions on how I could figure out the perfect amount of HCl added to precipitate out all of the AgCl without adding excess HCl?
I would love to not have to refilter the filtrate anymore.
We use concentrated HCl for this procedure.
(Another side note: full composition of this alloy is 80% Ag 15% In 5% Cd)

Comment: (1) I wonder more basically why a second filtration would be needed. Perhaps particle size increases? (2) To avoid two filtrations could you let the ppt's sit for 12-24 hours? Filter after sitting and see if you get more ppt on the third day.

Comment: Well we filter the samples for a second time because of AgCl precipitating out after the first filtration. I believe we add too much HCl so when the sample is dropping AgCl out some of the AgCl turns into the Ion AgCl2 which is soluble in excess HCl. We use concentrated HCl so it would make sense. We use 25 mL crucibles that are fitted with a 21 mm quantitative microfiber filter.

Comment: I understand that the excess $\ce{HCl}$ added would likely form $\ce{AgCl_2^-}$ but I don't understand why that anion would decompose to $\ce{AgCl}$ after a day. The only thing that I can think of is Ostwald ripening, but I'd wonder how much more $\ce{AgCl}$ that could create after a day.

Comment: Honestly thats the only thing I can think of as well its the only thing that makes sense.  The weight of the first filter AgCl is usually around 1.0554g and it is ideally supposed to be around 1.06 for a good Ag percentage. We usually get around .003 - .008 g of AgCl after the second filtration. And to answer part of your first question we usually let the sample sit on our hot plate for around 24 hours and bring it down and let it cool for around 6-7 hours then filter the sample.

Comment: dah... You first dissolve with $\ce{HNO3}$, then dilute with water and then add the $\ce{HCl}$. So the final acid mixture would seem to be a dilute solution of aqua regia. Wouldn't the $\ce{HCl}$ reacti with the $\ce{NO3^-}$, as it does with "proper" aqua regia, but more slowly since the solution is dilute?

Comment: It is just a dilute solution of HNO3- and HCl (miniscule amounts not able to make A.R.) with all sorts of metals in it. It's really interesting though since the silver is present the HCl doesn't react with the NO3- but instead goes for the silver precipitating AgCl. Aqua Regia is 3 parts HCl to 1 part HNO3-.

Answer (score 0):

One gram silver alloy contains $0.800$ gram silver, which is $\frac{0.800}{107.87} = 0.785 $ mmol $\ce{Ag}$. To be transformed into $\ce{AgCl}$, the same amount of $\ce{Cl}$ atoms, and the same amount of $\ce{HCl}$ is needed. The problem now is to find the volume of $\ce{HCl}$ solution containing $0.785$ mmole $\ce{HCl}$. Unfortunately the concentration of used $\ce{HCl}$ solution is not given. So the problem cannot be solved.

Edit : As Matt grives $\ce{HCl}$ concentration as $12.1$ M, the problem can be solved. $0.785$ millimole $\ce{HCl}$ is contained in a volume : V = $\frac{0.785·10^{-3} \mathrm{mol}}{12.1 \mathrm {mol/L}} = 0.0648$ mL. It is a rather small volume, about two or three drops.

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot. It is concentrated HCl. 12.1 M HCl